# Why did Phoebe live on the streets?

Tags: analysis, friends

When Phoebe's mum died, Phoebe says she went and lived on the street - but why? Surely before her mother died they would have lived in a house, why would someone take it away from them?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Phoebe mentions that her mother died *and* that her step-father was back in prison. Chances are that the house was taken away from both Phoebe and Ursula on account of them being too young and/or not having enough money to pay for the bills.